# BizTalk 2009 Visual Studio 2008 Deployment error

Tags: windows-server-2008, deployment, biztalk, visual-studio-2008

I'm currently trying out BizTalk 2009 for the first time. I'm by no means a BizTalk user/expert. The installation was quite a lengthy process but sticking to the Microsoft checklist, everything installed correctly without an issue on the first try.

My question may appear to be more stackoverflow-oriented, but my guess is that I have a system configuration issue that needs to be resolved.

The Setup (running VMWare Fusion 2.0) - all software from Microsoft is *trial* edition. I'm trying to work through several example tutorials and test deployments to make recommendations to management.

- Windows 2008 Server
- 2GB RAM
- 40GB HDD space
- Visual Studio 2008 Professional *SP1*
- Office 2007 Professional Plus
- SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

I'm currently trying out the tutorials on MSDN ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578030(BTS.10).aspx)) and so far everything has worked without a hitch. I've been able to build the solution with no problems. But when it comes to *deploying* the solution, that's when I get several *similar* error messages (apologies for the formatting as there are numerous messages):

> ```
> Error   1    Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> Error   2    at Microsoft.BizTalk.Gac.Fusion.IAssemblyCache.InstallAssembly(AssemblyCacheInstallFlag
> ```
>
> flags, String manifestFilePath,
>   FusionInstallReference referenceData)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Gac.Gac.InstallAssembly(String
>   assemblyPathname, Boolean force)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.BizTalkAssembly.GacInstall(String
>   assemblyLocation)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.BizTalkAssembly.PrivateDeploy(String
>   server, String database, String
>   assemblyPathname, String
>   applicationName)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.BizTalkAssembly.Deploy(Boolean
>   redeploy, String server, String
>   database, String assemblyPathname,
>   String group, String applicationName,
>   ApplicationLog log)
>
> ```
> Error    5    Failed to add resource(s). Change requests failed
> ```
>
> for some resources.
>   BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed
>   to complete end type change request.
>   Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) 
>   0    0
>
> ```
> Warning    6    Assembly "EAIOrchestrations, Version=1.0.0.0,
> ```
>
> Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>   depends on the following assemblies
>   that must be installed in the Global
>   Assembly Cache for runtime to succeed:
>       Assembly "EAISchemas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>
> ```
> Error    7    Assembly "EAIOrchestrations, Version=1.0.0.0,
> ```
>
> Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>   references the following assemblies
>   that must be deployed before deploying
>   this assembly:
>       Assembly "EAISchemas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>
> ```
> Error    8    Deploy operation failed.
> ""
> Assembly "EAIOrchestrations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> ```
>
> PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>   references the following assemblies
>   that must be deployed before deploying
>   this assembly:
>       Assembly "EAISchemas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>
> ```
> Error    9    at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.BizTalkAssembly.PrivateDeploy(String
> ```
>
> server, String database, String
>   assemblyPathname, String
>   applicationName)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.BizTalkAssembly.Deploy(Boolean
>   redeploy, String server, String
>   database, String assemblyPathname,
>   String group, String applicationName,
>   ApplicationLog log)
>
> ```
> Error    10    Deploy operation failed.
> ""
> Assembly "EAIOrchestrations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> ```
>
> PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>   references the following assemblies
>   that must be deployed before deploying
>   this assembly:
>       Assembly "EAISchemas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>
> ```
> Error    11    Failed to add resource(s). Change requests failed
> ```
>
> for some resources.
>   BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed
>   to complete end type change request.
>   Deploy operation failed.
>       ""
>       Assembly "EAIOrchestrations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>   references the following assemblies
>   that must be deployed before deploying
>   this assembly:
>       Assembly "EAISchemas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c697d29deb225ec9"
>   0    0

Now, at first glance looking at error #2 there appeared to be a problem with Visual Studio and the GAC. I tried installing the generated .dlls into the GAC manually (copying in windows/assembly) with no luck. Even though my user account is in the administrators group and all the BizTalk groups I couldn't install the dlls.

So, afterwards I logged in as the Administrator and was able to copy the dlls into the GAC and tried redeploying the solution (as my own user account) but the same error messages appeared. I'm out of ideas. I'm sure it's something simple as permissions as the obvious error message code points out E_ACCESSDENIED, I'm just not that familiar with BizTalk internally enough to try out anything else.

Any ideas or solutions would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run visual studio as administrator:

> Visual Studio does not let you deploy
>   a BizTalk project on a computer with
>   the User Access Control (UAC) feature
>   turned on unless you run Visual Studio
>   with administrative privileges. To run
>   Visual Studio with administrative
>   privileges, click Start, point to All
>   Programs, point to Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2008, right-click Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008, and then click Run
>   as administrator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd210272(BTS.10).aspx

Comment: Tried it out, and no error messages. I knew it would be simple, but I didn't realize it would be *that* simple. I keep forgetting about UAC. Many thanks, Shiraz!

Comment: Additionally, thanks for the MSDN URL. I wouldn't have found it had you not pointed it out.